# How to expand and click on angular tree component for testing in protractor?

Tags: angular, testing, protractor

I want to expand the tree which looks like [Tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY4YN.png)  and simultaniously I need to click on each element in protractors tests. All the elements are available in span's. The following code is allowing me to expand the tree only once and after that I am unable to take on any command.

```
element(by.css('.toggle-children-wrapper.ng-star-inserted.toggle-children-wrapper-collapsed')).click()
```

The span title code `element(by.css('span[title="L1"]')).click()` is only working for Level 1 elements.

Below is the code snippet for all the levels and the tree nodes as well.

Level 1

```
<tree-node-content ng-reflect-node="[object Object]" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-template="[object Object]"> 
<span _ngcontent-c5="" id="121" title="L1" class="ng-star-inserted">Level 1</span>
</tree-node-content>
```

Nodes when Collapsed

```
<tree-node-expander ng-reflect-node="[object Object]">
><span class="toggle-children-wrapper toggle-children-wrapper-collapsed ng-star-inserted">
  <span class="toggle-children"></span>
</span>
</tree-node-expander
```

Nodes when expanded

```
<tree-node-expander ng-reflect-node="[object Object]">
<span class="toggle-children-wrapper ng-star-inserted toggle-children-wrapper-expanded">
    <span class="toggle-children"></span>
</span>
</tree-node-expander>
```

I have many Level 1 elements, so how to make sure which one I am clicking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: right click element in chrome and select to get path to css, then use that?

Comment: no. it is not working..